# Why is WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder.UseConfiguration not passing config to the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

WebHost.CreateDefaultbuilder(args).UseConfiguration, is supposed to, by default, use the configuration for both the webhost and the application. 
ConfigureAppConfiguration is only used to configure the app, not the host.

The code below was working before, with no issues. 
After updating from .net core 2.1 to 2.2 and updating some nuget packages to support .net core 2.2 the code is no longer working.

I did find a dirty hack, but I want to get rid of this, as I'm afraid I may get some unwanted results in the future.

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseContentRoot(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    .UseConfiguration(ConfigurationService.Config)
    // Dirty hack to temp fix my problem
    //.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configuration => configuration.AddConfiguration(ConfigurationService.Config))
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseSerilog()
    .Build();
```

ConfigurationService.Config is a static ConfigurationRoot build before the webhost gets called. The ConfigurationService also starts logging, determines some directories and other things.

The returned config contains: environment, appsettings.json file, custom.json file and commandline providers. 
I know this is working for the host, because of the kestrel configuration in the custom.json file. 
Before all the changes, if I add a dependency to IConfigurationRoot I would also see the same providers.

Now I see the default .net core providers on IConriguration dependency
(chained, environment, appsettings, appsetting.development, commandline) (the most important one, my custom.json file is not here).

I have already tried by not using a static iconfiguration root, and build it in the same method that returns the WebHost, to no avail, so it has nothing to do with my ConfigurationService.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mistake.

I was trying to get the options from the serviceprovider passed through in one of my methods. But since the app was not started yet, I first had to build the serviceCollection manually.

Comment: hi, please accept your answer to close the cold case!?